# Rails3 Find Distinct gives result not object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to select the User Id as a variable in the console however I keep ending up with:

```
 [#<User id: 4>]
```

The find statement I have tried is:

```
 userid = User.select('id').where('username = ?', 'uwZgf')
```

I've also tried with find_by_sql with same result.

What do I need to get the value out instead of the hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've got there is an array of one `User` object.

```
User.select(...).where(...).first.id
```

Would do the trick (you'd probably want to check the value returned by `first` before trying to call `id` on it.

You might find

```
User.find_by_username('foo').try(:id)
```

more readable.

Comment: Cheers. Works perfectly. The second one's a nice looking query :) Thanks S